# How do I retrieve the string value of a letter in an array?

Tags: ruby, ascii

I am trying to retrieve the value of a letter in an array. The array I have is:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"].
```

If I want to retrieve a letter's value, the code is:

```
?a
```

However, when I tried `?a[5]` it gives me `0`. Does anyone know why this is the case?

--sorry to clarify I am using 1.8.7 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of associativity/precedence. `?a[5]` is interpreted as `(?a)[5]`, not as `?(a[5])`. I suppose you expected the latter, but it actually is the former.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as of Ruby 1.9. `?a` will give you the string "a", where it used to give you the ASCII code for that character. It's just another (limited) string literal mechanism at this point.

If you want a characters value, you need to use the `ord` method, as in `a[5].ord` or `?a.ord`.  `ord` is documented at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-ord

The behavior of the `?` operator and the String `[]` method when passed a single Fixnum changed at the same time in Ruby 1.9, with both returning a one-character string where they used to return a Fixnum.

As an aside, I can't find the documentation of the `?` operator in the Literals/String section of the same official reference.

Comment: could you link the documentation,i never have seen this method.

Comment: I know `String#ord`,but not `?a`.. Looking for the same.. where is it documented.. :)

Comment: Well, it's not in http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html, which one place I think it _should_ be.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.8 `?a == 'a'[0]`. Info about the [`?` operator](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html) (search for: "Integer and Floating Point Numbers")

Therefore you can get the value for a letter in the array `a` with:

```
a[5][0]
```

Whereas in Ruby > 1.9 use the method `ord`: `a[5].ord`

Comment: `?a == 'a'[0]` is still true in 1.9 and 2.0, since `'a'[0]` is "a" in 1.9 and 2.0

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Yes, you are right. But only because both method's return values have been changed in the same way.